# python regex to match only first instance

Tags: python, regex

I have a python code and i'm reading a certificate and matching only the root cert. For ex my certificate is as below:

```
--------begin certificate--------
CZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxGjAYBgoJkiaJk/IasdasdassZAEZFgp2aXJ0dWFsdnB4MSEw
HwYDVQQDExh2aXJ0dWFsdnB4LVZJUlRVQUxEQzEtQ0EwHhfdgdgdgfcNMTUwOTE2MTg1MTMx
WhcNMTcwOTE2MTkwMTMxWjBaMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGCgmSJoaeqasadsmT8ixkARkW
B3ZzcGhlcmUxFTATBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgVsb2NhbDEOMAwGA1UEChMFdmNlcnfrrfgfdvQx
CzAJBgNVBAMTAkNBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w
--------end certificate----------
--------begin certificate--------
ZGFwOi8vL0NOPXZpcnR1YWx2cHgtcvxcvxvVklSVFVBTERDMS1DQSxDTj1BSUEsQ049UHVi
bGljJTIwS2V5JTIwU2VydmldfsfhjZXMsQ049U2VydmfffljZXMsQ049Q29uZmlndXJhdGlv
bixEQz12aXJ0dWFsdnB4LERDPWxvY2FsP2NxvxcvxcvBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGU/YmFzZT9vYmpl
Y3RDbGFzcz1jZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uQXV0dsfsdffraG9yaXR5MD0GCSsGAQQBgjcVBwQwMC4G
--------end certificate----------
```

I want to fetch only the root certificate, which starts with CZImiZPy. I read the certificate into the variable data and applying the below regex

```
re.sub('-----.*?-----', '', data)
```

But it fetched both the encrypted certificates and not just the first one. Is there any better way I can tweak the regular expression?

Comment: Could you also provide the expected output?

Comment: @emre. the expected output is there, just the first `<certificate encrypted>`

Comment: @yzT: If that's OP wants then he shouldn't use `re.sub()` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to search for text, not substitute it with something else.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """--------begin certificate--------
<certificate encrypted>
--------end certificate----------
--------begin certificate--------
<certificate encrypted>
--------end certificate----------"""
>>> re.search(r"-+begin certificate-+\s+(.*?)\s+-+end certificate-+", s, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
'<certificate encrypted>'
```

**Explanation:**

```
-+begin certificate-+ # Match the starting label
\s+                   # Match whitespace (including linebreaks)
(.*?)                 # Match any number of any character. Capture the result in group 1
\s+                   # Match whitespace (including linebreaks)
-+end certificate-+   # Match the ending label
```

`re.search()` will always return the first match.

Comment: This doesn't give the correct output. It prints:
================================ RESTART ================================

Comment: @Sandy: I can't see that text in the sample you gave in your question. The regex works for that input - if it doesn't work with your "real world" data, you need to specify what your data actually looks like, otherwise all attempts at a useful regex are doomed...

Comment: Updated the data and question

Comment: @Sandy: The regex still works, and the text still doesn't contain `===RESTART===`. Are you sure you're using `re.search()` correctly? Are you assigning or printing the result (i. e. `print re.search(...)` or `result =  re.search(...); print result`)?

Comment: Thanks! It is working now. My mistake with the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub) can get a count variable as a parameter:

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> The *optional* argument `count` is the *maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced*..

If you want to only change the first match, do the following:

```
re.sub('-----.*?-----', '', data, 1)
```

Note that if you want to **extract**, you shouldn't use `re.sub`. Visit the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to learn about all available functions that help you extracting patterns from a string.

Comment: While true, this doesn't have any positive effect on the OP's (XY) problem. Reducing the number of replaces means that even more of the to-be-discarded text remains.

Comment: @TimPietzcker that's why I mentioned the last part. I just answered OP's question "regex to match only first instance". He's using `sub`, which accepts the count parameter.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Your answer is just an implementation of my answer's last part :) I just didn't want to give OP a ready solution. A minimal try from him might help him more.

Comment: The entire answer (except for the last paragraph, which should rather be a comment) is misleading. He's looking for the first match, and he's hoping to get it by removing all the non-matches. Your solution shows him how to remove only the first non-match. This isn't helping him/her.

Comment: @Maroun/kevin: I don't want to change anything. I just want to print the first <certificate encrypted>. The change you mentioned is not working for me.

Comment: @Sandy then see Tim's answer and if it works for you, accept it. I linked you to the module that has the right functions that should help you achieving what you want.

Comment: even if it didn't help the OP, your answer helped me and I had overlooked that part of the documentation, so +1

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Tim Pietzcker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33341778/3364859), this produces only the root certificate, which starts with `CZImiZPy`:

```
import re

certificates = """
--------begin certificate--------
CZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxGjAYBgoJkiaJk/IasdasdassZAEZFgp2aXJ0dWFsdnB4MSEw
HwYDVQQDExh2aXJ0dWFsdnB4LVZJUlRVQUxEQzEtQ0EwHhfdgdgdgfcNMTUwOTE2MTg1MTMx
WhcNMTcwOTE2MTkwMTMxWjBaMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGCgmSJoaeqasadsmT8ixkARkW
B3ZzcGhlcmUxFTATBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgVsb2NhbDEOMAwGA1UEChMFdmNlcnfrrfgfdvQx
CzAJBgNVBAMTAkNBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w
--------end certificate----------
--------begin certificate--------
ZGFwOi8vL0NOPXZpcnR1YWx2cHgtcvxcvxvVklSVFVBTERDMS1DQSxDTj1BSUEsQ049UHVi
bGljJTIwS2V5JTIwU2VydmldfsfhjZXMsQ049U2VydmfffljZXMsQ049Q29uZmlndXJhdGlv
bixEQz12aXJ0dWFsdnB4LERDPWxvY2FsP2NxvxcvxcvBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGU/YmFzZT9vYmpl
Y3RDbGFzcz1jZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uQXV0dsfsdffraG9yaXR5MD0GCSsGAQQBgjcVBwQwMC4G
--------end certificate----------
"""

regex = "-+begin certificate-+\s+CZImiZPy(.*?)\s+-+end certificate-+"

root_certificate = re.search(regex, certificates, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(root_certificate.group(0))
```

Output is

```
--------begin certificate--------
CZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxGjAYBgoJkiaJk/IasdasdassZAEZFgp2aXJ0dWFsdnB4MSEw
HwYDVQQDExh2aXJ0dWFsdnB4LVZJUlRVQUxEQzEtQ0EwHhfdgdgdgfcNMTUwOTE2MTg1MTMx
WhcNMTcwOTE2MTkwMTMxWjBaMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGCgmSJoaeqasadsmT8ixkARkW
B3ZzcGhlcmUxFTATBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgVsb2NhbDEOMAwGA1UEChMFdmNlcnfrrfgfdvQx
CzAJBgNVBAMTAkNBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w
--------end certificate----------
```